# Room reservation query from SQL to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on conference room reservation application based by MongoDB. I have business entities:

```java
class Room {
    private String id;
    // ...
}

class RoomReservation {
   private String id;
   private String room_id;
   private String user_id;
   private Date start;
   private Date end;
   // ...
}
```

To find out any available conference rooms in a given period (start, end), I could have a query something like the following if I use a relationship database.

```sql
select * from room as r where r.id not in (
  select room_id from room_reservation as rr
  where (rr.start <= start and rr.end >= start)
  union
  select room_id from room_reservation as rr
  where (rr.start <= end and rr.end >= end)
  union 
  select room_id from room_reservation as rr
  where (rr.start >= start and rr.end <= end)
  union
  select room_id from room_reservation as rr
  where (rr.start <= start and rr.end >= end)
)
```

I can have a similar query statement for MongoDB. The approach won't be very effective however. Unlike an individual field returned in a SQL statement, a whole document data, RoomReservation needs to be returned as a result of a MongoDB query.

Is the aggregation more suitable for this problem? If so, how to use aggregation operations to solve this problem?

Comment: @Sepehr Lajevardi Thanks Sepehr for your editing.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something here the union queries were even overkill here. In essence this is asking that the items contained within each condition set are **not** part of the results obtained from the collection.

This is what a [**`$nor`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator in MongoDB does by making sure than none of the conditions specified are met in selection of the documents.

In essence the structure is like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$nor": [
        { "start": { "$lte": start }, "end": { "$gte": start } },
        { "start": { "$lte": end },   "end": { "$gte": end } },
        { "start": { "$gte": start }, "end": { "$lte": end } },
        { "start": { "$lte": start }, "end": { "$gte": end } }
    ]
})
```

Not sure of the helper method construction without firing up an IDE, but the operators here should be what you are generally looking for the query structure to come out as.

--

Using the helper methods from spring data:

```js
    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(
        new Criteria().norOperator(
                Criteria.where("start").lte(start).and("end").gte(end),
                Criteria.where("start").lte(end).and("end").gte(end),
                Criteria.where("start").gte(start).and("end").lte(end),
                Criteria.where("start").lte(start).and("end").gte(end)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Maybe you should check also if the field exists or not, just in case that you only want the results that have those fields

Comment: @Eylen That is true since `$nor` would return if the fields do not exist as you suggest ( I believe ). I'm personally not sure of the last line of logic in the query as posed in the question as I think that is excluding valid documents, but just giving the literal translation and hoping the fields do exist.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the documentation documents without those fields will be also returned. If it's wanted to not include them, you can play with $exists http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/#nor-and-exists

Comment: @Eylen  yes I did already include a link. You must note that spring data and most wrapping ODM's are implemented quite literally. So whilst MongoDB documents can "possibly" not contain all fields, it would generally not be common place for that to happen. But yes I agree. Complete paranoia demands that you "should" add an `$exists` check for the fields in question

Comment: If my understand is correct, the above query returns all RoomReservations which are not in the given period,but not all rooms available in the given period. If so, that isn't what I want.